# Fill grid with instances for puzzles

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to fill grid with instances like on picture. Different colors are different plane instances.

[image]

Comment: Does the green rectangle correspond to 4 instances?

Comment: Yes, they are the same but scale is different.